# Populating different tables from a single JSON file in Redshift

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to load multiple tables Redshift from one S3 JSON file and ignore the objects that don't exactly match my JSONpaths?

I have the following two tables in Redshift:

```
create table employee
(
       employee_id int,
       employee_name varchar(50),
       employee_age int,
       department_id int,
       created_date timestamp
);
create table department
(
       department_id int,
       department_name varchar(50),
       created_date timestamp
);
```

My JSON file "employee_department.json"(containing both employee and department data):

```
{
    "employee_id": 1,
    "employee_name": "Jack",
    "employee_age ": 38,
    "department_id": 100,
    "created_date": "2016-11-07 10:00:00"
}
{
    "employee_id": 2,
    "employee_name": "Jill",
    "employee_age ": 26,
    "department_id": 101,
    "created_date": "2016-11-07 11:00:00"
}
{
    "department_id ": 1,
    "department_name ": "Sales",
    "created_date": "2016-01-01 03:00:00"
}
{
    "department_id ": 2,
    "department_name ": "Finance",
    "created_date": "2016-01-01 04:30:00"
}
```

Manifest file "employee_department_manifest.manifest":

```
{
  "entries": [
    {"url":"s3://mybucket/employee_department.json","mandatory":true}
  ]
}
```

Two JSON path files "employee_jsonpath.json" & "department_jsonpath.json":

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
        "$['employee_id']",
        "$['employee_name']",
        "$['employee_age']",
        "$['department_id']",
        "$['created_date']"
    ]
}


{
    "jsonpaths": [
        "$['department_id']",
        "$['department_name']",
        "$['created_date']"
    ]
}
```

The following COPY commands will work, but as per the screenshots below, I end up with 4 records in each table rather than the expected 2 and the wrong `department_id` data is loaded into the departments table. Is there a way to restrict the COPY to records that meet the JSONpaths files exactly, and ignore the others? I realise that in this case I could split JSON into two separate files, but it would be good to know if this is possible.

```
COPY employee
FROM 's3://mybucket/employee_department_manifest.manifest'
CREDENTIALS ''
JSON 's3://mybucket/employee_jsonpath.json'
MANIFEST;
COPY department
FROM 's3://mybucket/employee_department_manifest.manifest'
CREDENTIALS ''
JSON 's3://mybucket/department_jsonpath.json'
MANIFEST;
```

.

```
select * from employee;
```

[image]

```
select * from department;
```

[image]